# Polar accesslink API POST users not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I'm currently trying to implement Polar accesslink API on an app, but when trying to POST a new user I still get this error:

> url: 'https://www.polaraccesslink.com/v3/users/',
> status: 400,
> statusText: 'Bad Request',
> headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
> counter: 0

I already have the authorization token, which I know expires every 10 min, and I'm using the service through a function that takes the token and the `userID` as parameters. This is my code:

```
 postUser(memberId: string, token: string) {
    const inputBody = { 'member-id': memberId };
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/xml', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    };
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(inputBody)
    }
    return new Promise<object>((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch('https://www.polaraccesslink.com/v3/users', options)
    .then(function(res: any) {
      console.log(res)
      return res.json();
    }).then(function(body: any) {
      console.log(body);
    });
  })
}
```

I'm implementing it the same way as it is specified in `https://www.polar.com/accesslink-api/?javascript--nodejs#users` but really don't know what might I be doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have experience with this specific API but i can see you send in the header `Content-Type` the value `application/xml` but the request body is JSON formatted.
Try send `application/json` in that header.
The `Content-Type` header is used in HTTP to specify the body mime type.
more info in: [Content-Type HTTP Header - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)

I also see this is the exact code in the sample but notice they have 2 sample requests and 2 sample results, one in XML and one in JSON each.

Comment: and i know this isn't a code review but i don't see any reason to use `new Promise()` here as fetch return a promise. if inside one of the `then` blocks you need to wrap a callback based function you can use the promise constructor just for that call and `return` the new promise in the `then` block. they will chain together.

Answer (score 0):

Any ideea why this POST gives 'invalid_Request'?

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://polarremote.com/v2/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=1f9edc0c5e60a0bab4fd3f1f00571a58' --header 'Authorization: Basic ... DA4OS05ZDc2LTJlNTQwZjFkZTc5ZA==' --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --header 'Accept: application/json'
```

Comment: for POST content type  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' you need specify data as follows, it worked for me.

curl -v --request POST 'https://polarremote.com/v2/oauth2/token' -d "grant_type=authorization_code&code=****" --header 'Authorization: Basic ****' --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --header 'Accept: application/json'

Another reason is that you migth forgot that you sepcified redirect_uri in authorization end point. 
See docs: redirect_uri - Must be specified if redirect_uri was passed to authorization endpoint